# how to link to second-level heading in external org file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I create, in an org mode file, a link to a second-level heading located in another org mode file?

I can do this for a first-level file with

```
[[file:external-file.org::*first-level heading][description]]
```

but I haven't been able to find a way to do this for second level headings. I've already tried with

```
[[file:external-file.org::*first-level heading**second-level][description]]
[[file:external-file.org::*first-level heading/**second-level][description]]
[[file:external-file.org::*first-level heading::**second-level][description]]
```

and none of them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html) says this:

> `file:projects.org::*task title` heading search in Org file

Note that this says "heading search", not "level-one heading search". No mention is made of the number of asterisks having to match the heading level. In your example, this should work:

```
[[file:external-file.org::*second-level][description]]
```